# How to identify found clusters in Lumer Faieta Ant clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have been experimenting with Lumer-Faieta clustering and I am getting 
promising results:

[image: Lumer-Faieta ant clustering]

However, as clusters formed I was wondering how to identify the final clusters? Do I run another clustering algorithm to identify the clusters (that seems counter-productive)?

I had the idea of starting each data point in its own cluster.  Then, when a laden ant drops a data point, its gets the same cluster as the data points that dominates its neighborhood. The problem with this is that if clusters are broken up, they share share the same cluster number.

I am stuck.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I employed DBSCAN as a post processing step.  The effect as follows:

[image: DBSCAN as post-processing step]

Given that we have a projection of a high dimensional problem on a 2D grid, with known distances and uniform densities, DBSCAN is ideal for this problem.  Choosing the right value for epsilon and the minimum number of neighbours are trivial (I used 3 for both values).  Once the clusters have been identified, it can be projected back to the n-dimension space.

See [The 5 Clustering Algorithms Data Scientists Need to Know](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-5-clustering-algorithms-data-scientists-need-to-know-a36d136ef68) for a quick overview (and graphic demo) of DBSCAN and some other clustering algorithms.